# How can i fix the GTK hightlighted contex menues problems?

Tags: gnome, gtk, ati

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiXUP.png) a screenshot of the trouble I'm experiencing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a theme problem so to fix it you can do two things:

1. Report a bug to the creator of the theme and wait for a fix.
2. Edit manually `.css` files in `/usr/share/themes/THEME_NAME` and try to fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah but with line in my css file am I supposed to modify